# Variance of a fair coin toss with standard uniform random variable

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be the standard uniform random variable. That is, $X$ has the density $f_X(x) = 1$ for $0 < x < 1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Suppose we toss a fair coin (independently of the value of $X$) and set

$Y = \left\{\begin{matrix} X\text{ if the coin shows "heads",}\\1\text{ if the coin shows "tails".} \end{matrix}\right.$

(a) Calculate Var$(Y^p)$ for any $p > 0$.
(b) Calculate the limit of Var$(Y^p)$ as $p\to\infty$. Can you think of a way to figure out that limit without having to do first the calculation in part (a) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=Y^p$. A reasonable approach to calculating the variance of $W$ is to calculate $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$.

So first let us calculate $E(W)$.  We use a *conditional expectation* approach. With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we have $W=X^p$, and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ we have $W=1^p=1$.

If $W=X^p$, then $E(W)=\int_0^1 x^p \,dx=\frac{1}{p+1}$. And if $W=1$ then $E(W)=1$. It follows that
$$E(W)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{p+1}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{p+2}{2(p+1)}.$$
More formally, let random variable $H$ be equal to $1$ if the coin toss results in a head, and $0$ otherwise. Then
$$E(W)=E(W|H=1)\Pr(H=1)+E(W|H=0)\Pr(H=0).$$

For $E(W^2)$, the calculation is very similar. Now calculating $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$ is routine.

For the intuition about the limit, note that if $p$ is very large, and we tossed a head, then $Y^p$ is very likely to be close to $0$.

Comment: Thanks! This answer psychs me up.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Just a correction, your calculation for *E(W)* is wrong. *E(W) = (p+2)/(2p+2)*. The process is correct though.

Comment: Sorry but E(W) cannot be at the same time 1/(p+1), 1, and (p+2)/2 (or the correct answer (p+2)/(2p+2)).

Comment: @Schnokeyboy: Thank you, I had left out part of the denominator.